# YML syntax error

Tags: ruby, yaml

I want to have a multi-line bit of markdown java in a yam file. I tried many things but I guess I don't quite get the quoting rules of Yaml.

````
{
  title: Museum,
  body: |
      "```java
      code code code
      java2",
  answers: [
    "`museum`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3)`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`"
  ]
}
````

Produces:

```
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (generator/test.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 3 column 9 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Comment: Have you tried building the data as a Ruby hash, converting that to YAML, and seeing what it looks like? Or checking the specs at http://yaml.org ?

Comment: Good idea on the first, and on the second: yes I checked the specs and several other sources. It's just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

YAML has two styles: the JSON like [flow style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Flow) and the much better human readable [block style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Block).

Roughly speaking you can have nested structures each style nested within itself and can have flow style nested within block style, but b[lock style nested within flow style is not allowed](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2799181).

Your to level `{` and `}` are flow style but you try to introduce, with `|`,  a [literal block style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) scalar within that flow style. Replace the flow style with block style upwards from that scalar:

````
title: Museum
body: |
      "```java
      code code code
      java2"
answers: [
    "`museum`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3)`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`",
    "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`"
]
````

and your YAML is fine. Note that the double quotes "around" the value for the key `body` are not going to be stripped when loading, maybe that is not what you intended.

You should IMO not leave out the trailing `,` after the last value in the (flow style) sequence that is the value for `answers`. This will certainly lead to errors when you extend the list and forget to put in the trailing comma on the line above.

I would personally go for block style all the way:

````
title: Museum
body: |
      "```java
      code code code
      java2"
answers: 
- "`museum`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3)`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`"
````

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with YAML file generation that is convoluted or complex, or when it's not working as I expect, I revert to letting Ruby show me the way:

````
require 'yaml'

body = <<EOT
"```java
code code code
java2
"
EOT

answers = %w(
  `museum`
  `museum.getFloor(3)`
  `museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`
  `museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`
  `museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`
  `museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`
)

obj = {
  "title" => "Museum",
  "body" => body,
  "answers" => answers
}

puts obj.to_yaml
````

Which, in this case, outputs:

````
---
title: Museum
body: |
  "```java
  code code code
  java2
  "
answers:
- "`museum`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3)`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`"
- "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`"
````

If you then pass that YAML back into the parser, you should get the original data structure back:

````
YAML.load(obj.to_yaml)
# => {"title"=>"Museum",
#     "body"=>"\"```java\n" +
#    "code code code\n" +
#    "java2\n" +
#    "\"\n",
#     "answers"=>
#      ["`museum`",
#       "`museum.getFloor(3)`",
#       "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5)`",
#       "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator()`",
#       "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name`",
#       "`museum.getFloor(3).getExhibit(5).getCurator().name.toUpper()`"]}
````